# HyperLinking PNG images to open/download into an Outlook e-mail body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email, outlook

I have some customized PNG images in HTML pages. I want to Hyperlink these images in a way that when clicked they should download as a .MSG file. That is, it should give the option of opening in an Outlook email body straight away.
I'm not sure how to go about this. Whether I need to convert the PNG images to MSG files somehow. 
Any advice would be appreciated.

As a background, the HTML files are currently heavy on JavaScript that is used to customize the images by the user. The customized images can be saved as a PNG image by the user by right clicking the image and saving. I have avoided 'download' attribute because of its inconsistent support across browsers.

What I want is for the user to be able to load the final customized image to his/her email straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook will not let you run any scripts of navigate in the HTML body of an email. All navigation will be redirected to an external browser.

Comment: I don't want to run scripts in the HTML body of the email. I want the image to open in an email body. I've seen it being done, but don't know how to pull it off. In that case, it the image when clicked downloads as a .msg file.

Comment: It will not work since that will require navigation, which Outlook will not allow. You can have an image in an img HTML attribute referring to an attachment by its content id. The url can also be a cid instead of http, but still, that link will be opened in an external application.

Comment: Yes you are right. There's no way to do it. HTML's mailto attribute only works with text. The instance that I was referring to deals with static images. They store .msg files on the server, with the static images in the body. The .msg file downloads when a button (thumbnail) is clicked. There's no way to do this using customizable dynamic images it seems.